# Mysql : Count Posts and Group by date

Tags: sql, mysql, count, group-by

I am not very good at sql , generally I use php to do my complicated tasks , But in this task , there are lots of data , so using php for counting posts is very slow. So  I want a sql which counts post by date , but my date column in table is php's time stamp (int).I will crate  post number x date chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For not knowing SQL you seem to have a decent grasp on the terminology.

Something like this should work:

```
  SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date, '%Y %D %M') AS POST_DATE,
         COUNT(post_id) AS POST_COUNT
    FROM posts
GROUP BY POST_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about MySQL, but in postgres you could do something like (for a table named posts with at least the columns id and php_timestamp):

```
SELECT COUNT(id), php_timestamp - (php_timestamp % 86400) AS base_date
FROM posts
GROUP BY php_timestamp - (php_timestamp % 86400)
```

Of course, an index on the expression php_timestamp - (php_timestamp % 86400) would be highly recommended (not sure you can create one in MySQL though). This groups by the date in UTC.

Comment: "This groups by the date in UTC" - nothing in your query is related to UTC.

Comment: Unix time (which PHP uses) counts the number of seconds from UTC 1 Jan 1970. Then I'm rounding to the time of midnight of the nearest day in UTC.